# Mta application failing to deploy with conflict error

Tags: sapui5, launchpad, mta

I had deployed the app last on friday and it got deployed successfully.But since, today morning the deployment is not happening at all.It is checking for conflicting process and failing.
[image]

I'm doing this from the webide and i'm not able to check what are the conflicting process and how to resolve it.

Comment: Doesn't solve your Problem but FYI: [MTA Tool is coming to an end. The old tool will be available until June 30, 2020](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/11/19/enjoy-our-new-tool-for-building-mta-archives/)

Comment: @MrNajzs the original MTA build tool is coming to an end but the replacement is already available in WebIDE and on NPM. (MBT package)

Answer (score 0):

WebIDE lacks the ability to do proper investigation on deploying apps to SAP Cloud Foundry.

The best way to do this is to install the Cloud Foundry Multi-apps plugin (see [this tutorial](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/cp-cf-install-cliplugin-mta.html)). This will allow you to use the local terminal to control the deployment (or alternatively use SAP Business Application Studio which already has the commands built in).

Then use the command `cf mta-ops` to get the list of ongoing operations and `cf dmol <operation_id>` to download the logs for that operation. `cf deploy` can be used to abort/retry operations.